# When calculating percentage in Jupyter I am getting more information than needed

Tags: python, math, jupyter-notebook

This is the code I typed in Jupyter.

```py
# Calculate the overall passing percentage.
overall_passing_percentage = overall_passing_math_reading_count / student_count * 100
overall_passing_percentage
```

I just need the percentage number but I get this instead when running the code. More information than needed.

```
Student ID       65.172326
student_name     65.172326
gender           65.172326
grade            65.172326
school_name      65.172326
reading_score    65.172326
math_score       65.172326
School ID        65.172326
type             65.172326
size             65.172326
budget           65.172326
dtype: float64
```

Comment: this is the code before: # Calculate the number of students passing math.
passing_math_count = passing_math["student_name"].count()

# Calculate the number of students passing reading.
passing_reading_count = passing_reading["student_name"].count()

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more code, especially the part before you calculate the percentage. From what you have provided so far, it doesn't look like Jupyter would do that.